# Wordpress woocommerce shipping order

Tags: plugins

Hey guys can you please help me with something regarding the woocommerce plugin?

I want only these fields show up in the shipping section (i think it requires a reorder of the fields, but i don't know where to begin)

Name

Address 1

Adress 2

Email | Telephone

Company
FIELD 1 | FIELD 2 (for the company details)

Answer (score 1):

Address fields are controlled by the `WC_Countries` class and can be filtered via:

```
$address_fields = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_' . $type . 'fields', $address_fields, $country );
```

where there are 2 $types: billing and shipping.  Once you've found that it is just PHP array manipulation:

```
function reorder_shipping_fields( $address_fields ){

    if ( isset( $address_fields['shipping_company'] ) ){
        $shipping_company = $address_fields['shipping_company'];
        unset( $address_fields['shipping_company'] );
        $address_fields['shipping_company'] = $shipping_company;
    }

    return $address_fields;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'reorder_shipping_fields' );
```